# Compile sfml with conan and cmake

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, sfml, conan

I'm trying to compile sfml with cmake and conan package manager. Here is my conanfile.txt:

```
[requires]
sfml/2.5.0@bincrafters/stable

[options]
sfml:graphics=true
sfml:window=True
sfml:audio=True
sfml:network=True
sfml:system=True

[generators]
cmake

[imports]
```

And my cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)

project(projectx)

add_executable(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    src/main.cpp
    )

target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${CONAN_LIBS}
    )
    rtype
```

And when i compile here is my error :

```
ERROR: Unable to find 'sfml/2.5.0@bincrafters/stable' in remotes
```

Comment: This looks more like you are trying to use sfml precompiled by someone else.

Answer (score 4):

The bincrafters remote is deprecated IIRC. You should use the [conancenter](https://conan.io/center/) remote instead (this is already configured as one of your remotes in newer conan versions - check with `conan remote list` to be sure, it should list *'conancenter: https://center.conan.io [Verify SSL: True]'*).

In your `conanfile.txt` simply replace the `bincrafters/stable` part by `_/_` (I'm not 100% sure but maybe you don't need that `@_/_` part at all, i.e. `sfml/2.5.0` could suffice, already). The conancenter remote should be used.

Comment: Refer as `conancenter`, not `conan-center`. The `conan-center` remote is related to Bintray, which is deprecated too. The new Conan Center uses `conancenter` as remote name. Since Conan 1.40 `conan-center` won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I changed the answer to prevent misunderstandings.